# How to create an alias in Apache 2 that points to a network share?

Tags: apache-http-server, alias

I am trying to create an Alias directive with Apache 2.2, to point to a shared folder on other computer.

Apache is running on machine *M1* at IP `192.168.0.103`, the other machine *M2*, with the shared folder, is at IP `192.168.0.101`.

Now I am testing *M1* with Linux Ubuntu 12 and *M2* with Windows 7. I am editing `httpd.conf` on *M1*. There are two Alias directives:

```
Alias /m1test/ "/home/test/"
Alias /m2test/ "file://192.168.0.101/test/"
```

Testing:

- `http://localhost/m1test/foo.txt` - is OK!
- `http://localhost/m2test/foo.txt` - doesn't work

How can I make the second alias work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the UNC path instead of the network drive letter notation (which is pretty idiosyncratic to windows).

```
Alias /edrive //unc/path_here/
```

Apache knows nothing about 'drive letters'.

BTW... to find the unc path for a networked drive, run in the windows command terminal:

```
  C:\> net use
```

It should list  your drives and their unc's

Comment: Since i am using virtual box with win2008 my net use stands like this :\\vboxsrv\E_DRIVE. 
I made my alias like this :
Alias /MaliasE/ "\\vboxsrv\E_DRIVE\teste/" (where teste folder is fully shared. 
when using google chrome: localhost/MaliasE/ i get 404 not found 
What should i do next ? 
TY

Comment: Just changed as u said using foreward slash / instead of backslash \ and it worked

Comment: @josemey great!  Glad it worked out for you.  Any chance you'll switch to linux or mac ;) Please mark the answer correct and up vote it if it solved your issue.

Comment: Now we are using Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: Just to get a feedback on this. I used the UNC path but also needed to mount drivers between win and linux to share the directory also using samba. After all done, it worked out!

Comment: Re "net use", on my Win 7 PC, that command says "There are no entries in the list.". More usefully, "net view \\localhost" lists all Shared folders (whether root of a drive or not) on my PC. E.g. if it shows "Share name" of "Folder1", then that is accessible as "\\localhost\Folder1" locally, or from other computers as "\\mycomputername\Folder1" (from Windows) or "//mycomputername/Folder1" (from Linux).